# Change the size of an icon in shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, icons

How can I change the size of an `icon()` in shiny dashboard?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(skin = "purple",
                     options = list(sidebarExpandOnHover = TRUE),
                     header = dashboardHeader(
                       controlbarIcon = shiny::icon("filter")
                     ),
                     sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
                     body = dashboardBody(
                       tags$style(".fa-filter {color:red;size:26px}"),
                       
                     ),
                     controlbar = dashboardControlbar(
                       id = "controlbar",
                       collapsed = FALSE,
                       overlay = TRUE, 
                       skin = "light",
                       pinned = T
                     )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the CSS property `font-size` instead of `size`:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    skin = "purple",
    options = list(sidebarExpandOnHover = TRUE),
    header = dashboardHeader(
      controlbarIcon = shiny::icon("filter")
    ),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
    body = shinydashboard::dashboardBody(
      tags$style(".fa-filter {color:red; font-size:26px}"),
    ),
    controlbar = dashboardControlbar(
      id = "controlbar",
      collapsed = FALSE,
      overlay = TRUE,
      skin = "light",
      pinned = T
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
  }
)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6563
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Below please find two alternative ways not requiring a separate style tag:

```
library(shiny)
library(fontawesome)

shinyApp(
  basicPage(
    shiny::icon("filter", class = "fa-3x"),
    fontawesome::fa("filter", height = "3em")
    ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
  }
)
```

Furthermore, please check this [related article](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/icon.html).

---

Using your example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    skin = "purple",
    options = list(sidebarExpandOnHover = TRUE),
    header = dashboardHeader(
      controlbarIcon = shiny::icon("filter", class = "fa-3x", style = "color:red;")
      # controlbarIcon = fontawesome::fa("filter", height = "3em", fill = "red")
    ),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
    body = shinydashboard::dashboardBody(),
    controlbar = dashboardControlbar(
      id = "controlbar",
      collapsed = FALSE,
      overlay = TRUE,
      skin = "light",
      pinned = T
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
  }
)
```